# resize function with window width jQuery

Tags: javascript

```
  if ($(window).width() >= 320 && $(window).width() <= 480) {
    $(".projects").slice(1, 8).css("margin", "10px");
  } else {
    $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
  };
```

Its working good with default without resize finction. I try set this with:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {           
 })
```

But not working.
Any idea why?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz8pC/1/)

Comment: Seems to work to me. What exactly are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I want to change the slice when window width changed?

Comment: It does do that? Perhaps the problem is that it doesn't change back if the widths change?

Comment: The problem is only use the slice 1.8 when window resized not use slice 3.6 understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never resetting the div margins. Therefore, as soon as it get to the point where slice 1 through 8 have margins, they will never get changed back. You need to reset the divs:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".projects").css('margin', '0px'); // reset the divs
    if ($(window).width() >= 320 && $(window).width() <= 480) {
        $(".projects").slice(1, 8).css("margin", "10px");
    } else {
        $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
    };
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz8pC/2/)